# How to click a href button with no class, id or link text with Selenium

Tags: python

I am trying to click a herf in html on a website with no class, id, or link text. Is there any way to do this?

```
<a href="results/1931499577/swissadme.csv">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
```

This returns a list of all the elements of the given tag. If you find your element's position in the page you can use it. For example, if `<a href="results/1931499577/swissadme.csv"` is the third anchor tag in the web page then,

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[2]
```

Comment: I have already tried this I get <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="188F73C4-3727-4B12-883A-3482DD01636C", element="node-A9C2CDCB-71F3-418C-AA33-DD10B2BF80BA")> and an error that says element not intractable.

Comment: How about using `url = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[2].getAttribute('href')`and then manually going to url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `*driver name*.find_element_by_xpath('*xpath*')` followed by `.get_property('href')`, but that would work on the site if it is static. If it is, then you could assign `*driver name*.find_element_by_xpath('*xpath*').get_property('href')` to a variable, and using the variable inside `*driver name*.get(*nameofvaraible*)`.
`GetArribute` seems to not work, so therefore `get_property` must work.

Comment: *driver name*.find_element_by_xpath('*xpath*').get_property('href') did work! But it did give me the herf as a string and not a link that can be clicked which is what I needed.

Comment: Enclose `driver name.find_element_by_xpath('xpath').get_property('href')` with the `driver name.get()` if you want it the short way (but long in typing).

Comment: so it would be driver.get(driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').get_property('herf'))?